# Download GWT showcase project

Tags: gwt

I just can't find the link anywhere (anymore).

**Where can I download the Sourcecode for the [showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html)?**

I know, you can click on Sourcecode to get the Source code for the application, but there is on porject file for the whole application. I ask because I can't find the class `ContactCell` for the [CellTree](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree) Example (should be under import com.google.gwt.sample.showcase.client.content.cell.CwCellList.ContactCell; ).

BR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can browse thee sources directly from the svn:

[GWT Showcase SVN](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/?r=9045#showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/cell)

Comment: This repository has been moved to [Github](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/tree/master/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/cell) .

Answer (score 3):

It's right in the GWT SDK, downloadable at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/download or as an Eclipse plugin. In this last case, the SDK is exactly the same, unpacked into Eclipse's `plugins` subfolder.